# Optimal method for coping the clipboard C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

As many of you may know, `Clipboard.SetText(s)` has a probability of failure do to the reason of Clipboard been used by several UI applications.

A good overcome, of this problem is to use `Clipboard.SetDataObject(s,false,x,t)`. This approach limits the problems by limiting the probability of Clipboard copy to fail to small amount, however it doesn't solves entirely the problem (there is still a change we have a miss).

On the other hand Windows OS, in build method for coping and pasting, in any editor, never fails, as it is expected.

So my Question is does anybody knows how Windows implements `Clipboard.Copy()` in order to be used in a C# application?

```
string  result = result.Substring(x + 3, 24);
                Thread newThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
                newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                newThread.Start();

 public void ThreadMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(result, false, 5, 200);

                    keybd_event(0x11, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
                    keybd_event(0x56, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
                    keybd_event(0x56, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                    keybd_event(0x11, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                    keybd_event(0x0D, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
                    keybd_event(0x0D, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what _problem_ you're trying to solve.  Windows doesn't implement .NET methods - .NET methods are implemented in the CLR (which likely call native Win32 methods in this case)

Comment: I've *never* seen `Clipboard.SetText` or `SetDataObject` fail. How do you reproduce this?

Comment: I will add code where it fails..

Comment: In the above code used to have Cliboard.setText() and I had 50% misses

Comment: changing to dataObject missed only few times but I am still missing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar situation where after copying the contents to clipboard, I was unable to get it, for the same I tweaked the code, to retry the copying three times and after that I found the problem reduced, and if the problem persist then I informed user to retry copying the contents again.

```
 private bool TryCopyToClipboard(string contents)
    {
        int i = 0;
        bool IsCopied = false;
        while (i <= 3)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();
                System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(Body);
                if (System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText().Length == Body.Length)
                {
                    IsCopied = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {                   
                i++;
            }
        }

        return IsCopied;
    }
```